"gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found" - how to tell whether it is a gpg file?
I am trying to decrypt a file that I created back then in October 2009 on a Linux machine:
gpg -d mydata.tar.gpg

Instead of being prompted for the password (which I still keep), I am getting an error:
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof

This is using gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.10 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Linux 2.6.32-64-Generic)
Since a very long time passed since then, I no longer recall how I created that file. Is there any way to tell what type of tool and version created it?
(running file mydata.tar.gpg only yields: data)

UPDATE: Thanks to the comment below by @dave_thompson_085, I can indeed see a difference between the headers of decryptable .tar.gpg files and the one I am unable to decrypt.

The decryptable files all start with 8c 0d 04 02 03 02 .
The problematic file starts with b6 ef c2 36 b4 16


Dump an initial chunk and look at it -- I like od -tx1 [-N 128] or where available xxd -l128 (ell one two eight). To be clear this can narrow down what created the file, but not always to a single program (often several are compatible, by design) and almost never to a single version (most program features stay the same for many versions).

@dave_thompson_085 Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you
